# How to override one variable in frameset for a site

Tags: browser

There is a site that I don't control that displays terribly for the purposes I use it for. I'd like override its layout.

If I "inspect element" I can adjust the site to look how I want it to, but that change obviously isn't permanent. Here's what I want to do.

Current:

```
<frameset rows="245,50,*" border="0" id="FRRIGHT">
```

What I want:

```
<frameset rows="625,50,*" border="0" id="FRRIGHT">
```

Is there any way I can do this, in any browser? I apologize if I am asking in the wrong place. I really have no idea where else to ask.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, but the typical way off achieving this is using a browser extension like grease monkey. You could also just save a small JS snippet, then paste it into the console when you use the site.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I'm trying to use greasemonkey and don't even know where to begin. I tried this user script:

document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(/245,/g,"625,");

But it did not work.